# Help me with query string parameters (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, query-string

I'm creating a newsletter.

Each email contains a link for editing your subscription:

```
<%= edit_user_url(@user, :secret => @user.created_at.to_i) %>
```

**:secret => @user.created_at.to_i** prevents users from editing each others profiles.

```
def edit
  @user = user.find(params[:id])
  if params[:secret] == @user.created_at.to_i
    render 'edit'
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

It doesn't work - you're always redirected to root_path.

It works if I modify it like this:

```
def edit
  @user = user.find(params[:id])
  if params[:secret] == "1293894219"
  ...
```

1293894219 is the "created_at.to_i" for a particular user.

Do you have any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if params[:secret] == @user.created_at.to_i.to_s
```

The parameter is a string not an integer.

Comment: Big thank you to you sir :) I should learn more about this stuff

Comment: No problem! I remember it was big learning curve - I still get caught out by things like this.